Who was under the console when James Kirk was arguing with Matt Decker?
In "The Doomsday Machine", someone is seen below the console when Kirk and Decker argue:

DECKER: I'm in command here, Jim.
(Red-uniformed officer carefully escapes from under the console.)


Image for reference please

Here is a link for reference

@SteveV That's another scene with a person under the console which may or may not be related to my original question.  My question was related to the person under the console when Kirk and Decker were arguing.

Thank you for accepting my answer! I am actually working to improve it with screenshots and additional details. (Spoiler: still no clue who the actor is.) Just gotta get an account hiccup resolved first...

@leek - SteveV did in fact link to the scene you're talking about. The clip is unfortunately edited in such a way that it excludes the dialogue you mentioned and most of Kirk and Decker's argument, but it is the same scene, and that is the same officer lying beneath the console. If you're still unconvinced of this, check the full episode for yourself (if you have access to it) or the transcript.

I cannot identify the actor at this time, nor can I post screenshots at this time. As such, I will try to provide a partial answer that might help the next person to come along, should somebody else beat me to it.
Finally able to capture and upload screenshots, I have heavily edited this answer and added screenshots along with additional details. Sadly, no progress was made in identifying either mystery engineer. Alas.
The scene in question occurs at the 32:38 mark of the TOS Remastered episode of The Doomsday Machine. This engineer can be seen emerging from beneath the console:

At this point, the extra's face is on-screen and only somewhat clear and free of motion blur for a fraction of a second. If we were giving a description of the suspect, I would say they are male, Caucasian, dark hair, mid-to-late late 30's or early 40's in age. (We can only hope that someone with some sort of overzealous-resolution Blu-Ray release or some such can provide higher-resolution screen caps.)
Note that this character is dressed in a red engineering jumpsuit, not a "redshirt" security officer uniform. This tells us we're looking for a performer who played an engineer.
Memory Alpha's Unknown Performers article has no entries for The Doomsday Machine, but the episode page itself lists two unknown "Engineering technicians".
The first is our fellow:


The second uncredited (or so I thought) "Engineering technician" appears in the transporter room at multiple points throughout the episode, such as 14:41, 16:41, and 44:16, looking pretty much like this the entire time:


This certainly appears to be a different actor from the mystery person found during the bridge scene described in the question. Chiefly, the two actors' hairlines are quite dissimilar. The first mystery actor also has detached earlobes, while the second does not.

So who are these people?
IMDB credits the following extras/uncredited actors who might possibly fit this actor's description (i.e. correct age, gender, and/or hair color) :

Jerry Catron
Eddie Paskey
Roger Holloway
Tim Burns
Bill Blackburn

Of those, Jerry Catron plays security officer Montgomery who escorts Decker off the bridge at the end of this scene. He has been sporadically visible at his post throughout the scene. He can be eliminated.

Eddie Paskey has a recurring role as Lt. Leslie, who appears in multiple episodes, including a fair amount of dialogue in the episode "This Side of Paradise." As well, the unknown actor does not resemble him. I think he can safely be eliminated.

Memory Alpha has taken the liberty of identifying another actor for us. Tim Burns is shown in command yellow, and additionally appears to have lighter-colored hair than the dark-haired mystery engineer.

Similarly, Memory Alpha's entry for William Blackburn 's character eliminates him from consideration, showing this actor with a hairstyle, hair color, and uniform that does not match the mystery character.

When first reviewing this episode, I fast-forwarded to the bridge scene in question around the 32:00 mark. I grabbed the various screen caps of the mystery engineers shown above, all the time lamenting the lack of clear shots of the two actors' faces.
Lo and behold, there was a blink-and-you'll-miss it reaction shot much earlier in the episode that I had overlooked...because I blinked and missed it.
At 19:21, we got this reaction shot, showing both (!) unnamed, uncredited engineering technicians:

But wait! IMDB listed five uncredited actors, and you only eliminated four! What about Roger Holloway?
Roger Holloway's character entry on Memory Alpha shows him in redshirt uniform in various episodes (and his actor page shows him as an extra in at least one non-Starfleet role), and the article suggests that he appears in The Doomsday Machine but did not include his character's photo.  And here he is:

Note that this actor has a distinctive cleft chin. On that basis, I originally felt mostly confident in identifying him as the mystery engineer in the transporter room:

Then, I found the aforementioned reaction shot at 19:21, and something fell into place!
....No, wait, they're not the same person.

Alas. We have eliminated the 5 credited uncredited male actors listed on IMDB, and we are still no closer to determining who these people are, particularly this guy:

Based on all of the above, my answer is: there is no way to determine the identity of the actor in question at this time.
